# How do I center my YAML heading in an R markdown html document?

Tags: html, r, shiny, yaml, r-markdown

I want to have my YAML header information centered on my html document.

I want everything else left alligned as normal.

Can I apply any html or other code to the YAML header to make this happen?

How do I do this??

Example:

I have:

```
---
title: "Shiny HTML Doc"
author: "theforestecologist"
date: "Apr 14, 2017"
output:  html_document
runtime: shiny
---
```

Comment: Are you talking the resulting title/author/date about when it's rendered? That's a product of any CSS applied.

Comment: @alistaire yes. I can't figure out how to do it. Since this text is in the YAML, I assume I cannot apply normal HTML or css code into the YAML??

Comment: The YAML gets passed as parameters through `render` to the output format supplied (`html_document`), which is itself a function. It all gets rendered to markdown (including the title/etc.), which pandoc converts to HTML. If an external CSS stylesheet is supplied, it actually doesn't get applied until a browser renders it. Consequently, the simplest way to alter the appearance of the title is simply to supply an external stylesheet with selectors specific to the elements you want to change.

Comment: Ok thanks. So I'm brand new at this (started this week) -- what exact selectors do I need to center the YAML text?

Comment: How specific you need to be depends on what else is on the resulting page. It looks like everything gets chucked in a div with an ID of "header", though, so applying styles to everything within `div#header` would probably do the trick. [Here's some docs.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is some css styling that you can use to accomplish what you need.

- The markdown document title uses the `h1.title` CSS selector
- The markdown document author field uses the `h4.author` CSS selector
- The markdown document datea field uses the `h4.date` CSS selector

Here is the code:

````
---
title: "Shiny HTML Doc"
author: "theforestecologist"
date: "Apr 14, 2017"
output:  html_document
runtime: shiny
---

<style type="text/css">

h1.title {
  font-size: 38px;
  color: DarkRed;
  text-align: center;
}
h4.author { /* Header 4 - and the author and data headers use this too  */
    font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: DarkRed;
  text-align: center;
}
h4.date { /* Header 4 - and the author and data headers use this too  */
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: DarkBlue;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>


# H1 Header

Some body text

## H2 Header

More body text



```{r echo=T}
n <- 100
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(n),y=rnorm(n))
```
````

And this is what it looks like in then end:

[image]

Comment: perfect! Thank you! :)